# Writing  an integer into an ifstream C++

Tags: c++, file-io

Okay, so,  I can now read from .txt files as variables, but how do I write the integers once changed back into my text file?
Example:

```
xps.open ("xp.txt"); //Text file is loaded and applied to ifstream 'xps'
int xp;
xps >> xp; //xps is applied to integer xp
xp += 50; //xp has 50 added to it's value
```

and then I want the value of xp to be written (overwriting the previous number) into xp.txt, so how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the text file for both reading and writing; declare xps as an fstream and then you can just do

```
xps << xp
```

Answer (score 0):

It's inefficient to write and overwrite the same value.  Just wait until you know what value you want to write to the file, and write it.

I presume you mean `ofstream` rather than `ifstream` since you are writing to the file in this question.  If you absolutely have to go back in the file then you need to call [`seekp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/). In order to do this you need to remember the point in the file to start writing to which you can get by calling `tellp()`. So, if you want my advice, try not to have to re-write the value.